# How can I imitate the feature like alert() in Javascript to block the page?

Tags: javascript, alert

Because the alert really seems not friendly to users, so how can I finish it?

How can I imitate the feature like `alert()` in Javascript to block the page?

Comment: What do you mean by "blocking the page"?

Comment: That's not enough information. And what are you trying to `finish`?

Comment: By blocking the page, do you mean dimming the page?

Answer (score 2):

Use somethig like `jquery BlockUI` plugin like https://github.com/malsup/blockui/ , which will block the screen till system finishes the process.You can show nice custom message/animation to the user via BlockUI

Comment: +1, also will add jQuery UI's modal which will allow blocking: http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/dialog/modal.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing, but if you want to pop up a window and block what's going on behind the page until the window is closed (whether by the site or by the user), [jQuery UI modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal) works really nicely.

But, remember to check any input that your expecting. You can't necessarily rely that the user won't work around it by disabling JavaScript, killing the pop-up, or whatever (since you can't really control that).